# Publisher send rate drops with multiple clients in rospy

Tags: rospy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We noticed this as part of testing the Applanix Driver, which is written entirely in Python. On some machines, the send rate of the /applanix/nav message drops from the normal 100 Hz to 40 or even < 10 Hz as soon as there are subscribers listening and using the topic.

To test this out, I created the [ros_py_tests](https://github.com/kshehata/ros_py_tests) [github] package. It's just a test harness with a rospy publisher set to publish Headers at 100 Hz, and rospy subscribers that listen check messages for time deltas and sequence numbers. I've copied the code below for reference, though do use the github version since I'll post updated code there.

```
# pub.py exerpt
pub = rospy.Publisher('test', Header, queue_size=10)
rospy.init_node('sender', anonymous=True)
rate = rospy.Rate(100)
msg = Header()
while not rospy.is_shutdown():
    msg.stamp = rospy.Time.now()
    msg.frame_id = "hello world %s" % msg.stamp
    pub.publish(msg)
    rate.sleep()
```

Here's the listener.

```
# sub.py excerpt
def callback(data):
    global last_seq
    # check that we haven't missed any messages
    if last_seq > 0 and data.seq != last_seq + 1:
        rospy.logerror("Sequence number mismatch: expected " + str(last_seq + 1)
            + " got " + data.seq)
    last_seq = data.seq

    # compare time stamps and print out
    rospy.loginfo("Received message with time " + format_time_str(data.stamp) + 
        ", delta " + format_time_str(rospy.Time.now() - data.stamp) + 
        ", message: " + str(data.frame_id))

rospy.init_node('listener', anonymous=True)
rospy.Subscriber("test", Header, callback)
rospy.spin()
```

There's a launch file included the package on GitHub that makes it really easy to start this test. Basic procedure:

1. Start the publisher
2. Start 5 of the listeners
3. rostopic hz /test

Here's the strange part: it works perfectly well in virtual machines. On every Ubuntu host machine we've tried it on, the rate drops drastically once the listeners are running.

What's going on here? Why does having listeners kill the rate of sending of the publisher?

**Update**

I've added a cpp version of the publisher and the subscriber. Here's the result of testing the combinations:

```
           |    Subscriber   |
Publisher  | Python |   C++  |
Python     |  Fail  |  Fail  |
C++        |  Pass  |  Pass  |
```

Looks like it's pretty solidly something in the Python publisher, since the subscriber doesn't seem to matter.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201524/publisher-send-rate-drops-with-multiple-clients-in-rospy/) by [KareemShehata](https://answers.ros.org/users/19983/kareemshehata/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2015-01-22

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [KareemShehata](https://answers.ros.org/users/19983/kareemshehata/) on 2015-01-22**:
I've now created [ros_comm issue #557](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues/557) for this.

**Comment by [KareemShehata](https://answers.ros.org/users/19983/kareemshehata/) on 2015-01-23**:
To anyone looking, it seems like this might be fixed in the latest version of rospy. If you can reproduce the problem on your machine, please try updating the ROS core packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Turns out this was a bug in rospy that has was fixed somewhere between rospy 1.10.2-0 and 1.10.11-0. We hadn't updated because of a package dependency problem. If you're seeing a problem like this in ROS hydro, make sure to update your packages, and do both an upgrade and a dist-upgrade!

---

Originally posted by [KareemShehata](https://answers.ros.org/users/19983/kareemshehata/) with karma: 61 on 2015-01-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Could this be due to the use of *synchronous publishing* in `rospy`?

Looking at the code you posted, I don't see an explicit `queue_size` declared for your publisher. According to [rospy/Overview/Publishers and Subscribers - queue_size: publish() behavior and queuing](http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Publishers%20and%20Subscribers#queue_size:_publish.28.29_behavior_and_queuing), the `queue_size` needs to be set for asynchronous publishing to work.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-01-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [KareemShehata](https://answers.ros.org/users/19983/kareemshehata/) on 2015-01-22**:
The queue_size is being set. It's on the first line of the excerpt from pub.py.

```
pub = rospy.Publisher('test', Header, queue_size=10)
```

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-01-23**:
Hm, must've been late last night when reading this. Seems you're right.

**Comment by [KareemShehata](https://answers.ros.org/users/19983/kareemshehata/) on 2015-01-23**:
No worries. I had to check myself to make sure. :)